# Only able to issue one sql statement from isql

Tags: sql-server, odbc, freetds, isql

I'm running Debian opening up an ODBC connection to an MSSQL database on the network. When I run isql I can issue one sql statement fine. If I issue the same request a second time it returns 0 rows. If I run the same command a third time the connection finally bails out and I have to close the current session and start a new isql. the first two requests look good in my log even though the second one always returns 0 rows but the third one fails with an EOF from server.

> ODBC][3270][1366728023.855922][SQLExecute.c][344]
>   Exit:[SQL_ERROR] DIAG [01000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unexpected EOF from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Actually I remember now I updated freeTDS to 0.91 and compiled them by hand and that's what seemed to have fixed my issue along with making sure I had the correct tds version for my version of MSSQL. Seems that for 2008 you should have 8.0 as the selected version. This doesn't seem documented anywhere on the freetds page though.

I have no idea what I did but everything is working now after fighting with this for two days. all I did was open my config files up again (freetds.conf, odbcinst.ini, odbc.ini) do a save and then close them. Not like I haven't done that a million times trying to solve my issue but after that everything is working now perfectly now. I can even do select * which I wasn't able to do before when isql worked on the first query but not subsequent ones.